# Tags to synonymise, merge or nuke

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I have just reached the 'can make tag synonyms', so thought making this discussion would be prudent.

Which tags should be synonymised, merged or nuked.  Discuss them here!

Comment: For ease of use maybe do one suggestion per post, to allow it to be voted on and discussed individually

Comment: In terms of voting, how many votes before we take action?

Comment: 24 hours from the time the answer was posted gives every timezone to have seen it, after 24 hours maybe take action then if it is positively voted? 1 person cannot make a synonymisation alone anyhow, it requires others to vote approval

Comment: The OP seems to be not a user any more, is anyone still monitoring this issue?

Comment: @FJC Yes, it is still being monitored.